# import statements in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, import, ecmascript-6

If I import in the app module e.g. ElementRef and when import a service, where the service makes use of ElementRef, do I have to import ElementRef again in the service?

Or more general: can I, e.g. in app.module, import all the needed elements from angular/core and make them available to all the directives, pipes and services, which are also imported in app.module.

Comment: No you can't , nope

Comment: You're confusing Angular modules with ES6 modules. Those are very different things. ES6 modules are used to avoid globals. Angular modules are used to group components, directives and pipes together as well as define some providers.

Answer (score 4):

You need to import them where you need to use them.

So, in `AppModule` you will import them to add them to `providers`, `declarations`, `imports`, etc.

And in your components, directives, pipes, modules, services, etc. You will need to import them again if you need to use them.

Example:

**AppModule**

```
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [ 
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule
    ]
})
export class AppModule {
    constructor() {
    }
}
```

**UserModule**

Here I will need Http to perform some http calls, so I will have to import it...

```
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
       HttpModule
    ],
    declarations: [],
    exports: [
        HttpModule
    ]
})
export class UserModule{
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The imports will only be visible/used in the class in which it has been imported.

```
 do I have to import ElementRef again in the service
```

Yes you will have to import it since the service class will not able able to access the imports in the app.module.

```
can I, e.g. in app.module, import all the needed elements from angular/core and make them available to all the directives, pipes and services, which are also imported in app.module
```

No this is not possible since only the app.module would be able to use its imports

Comment: Can you explain what is wrong? . The imports can only be used in that class

Comment: That is not correct. `import`s are used by modules to reference other modules. They have nothing to do with classes whatsoever. To be clear I do not mean Angular's `NgModule`s, I mean JavaScript modules.

Comment: The question has been asked for Angular 2 which uses Typescript. So my answer is the context of that.

Modules are classes only, with special decorators eg:- 

export class AppModule { }. this AppModule class becomes a module when you add @NgModule to it. 

Whatever you have imported inside the class AppModule is for the use of AppModule only

Comment: That is not so. Here is a complete module: `export default "hello";`

Comment: The question is vague but it clearly asks about `ElementRef` from `'@angular/core';` Also, it asks if, when consuming a service that uses `ElementRef` does `ElementRef` need to be imported from `'@angular/core'` again

Comment: And, you yourself say _"Yes you will have to import it since the service class will not able able to access the imports in the app.module."_, what else could you be talking about?

Comment: My understanding of the question is whether ElementRef  has to be imported in the service class , not whether it has to be imported in the class where you are using the service

Comment: Asked: _"do I have to import ElementRef again in the service?"_ Answered: _"Yes you will have to import it since the service class will not able able to access the imports in the app.module."_. By your own definition of module, a service class would not be a module - your statements make no sense.